# How do you enumerate child properties recursively with an entity tree structure?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Entity Framework (Code First)
C#

I've got a tree structure with nodes in a one-to-many structure.

```
Node
|
\--- Children
```

I need all the Children (ICollection) to be enumerated. Currently, this is how I've got the code looking:

```
using (DBContext context = new DBContext()
{
    parentNode = (from query in context.Tree
                  where query.IsSomeWayToIDTheParentNode
                  select query).ToArray();

}

var tree = SomeRecursiveTreeBuilderMethod(parentNode);
```

In this code, the 1st level Children property on the parentNode is enumerated but the actual child nodes' Children properties are not enumerated and therefore throw ContextDisposed exceptions.

I've tried adding .Include(inc => inc.Children) to both the entire query (after the parens) and after context.Tree but with no luck. I can easily enough have a recursive 'ChildEnumerator(parentNode)' method be called inside the using statement which forces the enumeration but I feel there has to be a better way of ensuring that the object and child objects (n-deep) are all fully populated at the point of escaping the context scope.

Comment: Did you try `var tree = SomeRecursiveTreeBuilderMethod(parentNode.ToList());` to force enumeration upon first call?

Comment: That method cannot force the enumeration because it is outside the scope of the context and therefore when node.Children gets called on a level lower than the parent node, it tries to enumerate against the context which is disposed and throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that... why not moving the recursive function call inside the `using` statement then?

Comment: Doable, as a general rule I prefer to limit the exposure of the DBContext as much as possible. I don't generally like the idea of having a method (SomeRecursiveTreeBuilderMethod) that can only be called when wrapped externally in a using statement. I'm hoping there's a way to enumerate all child objects with syntax inside the LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

Include should work if it's formatted properly, so something like this:

```
using (DBContext context = new DBContext()
{
    parentNode = context.
        .Tree
        .Include(inc => inc.Children)
        .Where(query => query.IsSomeWayToIDTheParentNode)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Here's the official documentation for [DbExtensions.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: This works to enumerate children one tier down but now 2nd generation (or lower) children.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you expect:

```
List<Tree> parentNodes = new List<Tree>();

using (DBContext context = new DBContext()
{
    parentNodes = (from query in context.Tree
                   where query.IsSomeWayToIDTheParentNode
                   select query).ToList();
}

var tree = SomeRecursiveTreeBuilderMethod(parentNodes);
```

Comment: This might not work because by the time your are calling SomeRecursiveTreeBuilderMethod(parentNodes), the context is already disposed via the using. Also, there's no need for parentNodes to be enumerated into a List when an array will do.

Comment: That was precisely the goal when calling the `ToList` method: to force the query evaluation, as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). HTH